# Javascript how to add style="display:none" to <div> by checking <li> inline style?

Tags: javascript

Javascript check how to add `style="display:none"` to `<div>` by checking `<li>` inline style ?

- As per above code by default all `<li>` having `style="display:none"`.
- Now I want javascript should check all `<li>` as `style="display:none"`.
- If all `<li>` having `style="display:none"` then `<div>` Food also render as `<div style="display:none">` Food

```html
HTML code:

<div> Food <!-- Main Category -->
 <ul> 
      <li style="display:none"> Pizza </li>    <!-- Category Child Item -->
      <li style="display:none"> Falafel </li>    <!-- Category Child Item -->
      <li style="display:none"> Donuts </li>    <!-- Category Child Item -->
      <li style="display:none"> Burger </li>    <!-- Category Child Item -->
      <li style="display:none"> Cheese Sandwich </li>  <!-- Category Child Item -->
 </ul>

</div>

Require - HTML code output by javascript:

<div style="display:none"> Food <!-- Main Category -->
 <ul> 
      <li style="display:none"> Pizza </li>    <!-- Category Child Item -->
      <li style="display:none"> Falafel </li>    <!-- Category Child Item -->
      <li style="display:none"> Donuts </li>    <!-- Category Child Item -->
      <li style="display:none"> Burger </li>    <!-- Category Child Item -->
      <li style="display:none"> Cheese Sandwich </li>  <!-- Category Child Item -->
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```js
var allHidden = true;
$("#food ul li").each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":visible")){
        allHidden = false;
    }
});

if(allHidden){
   $("#food").hide();       
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="food"> Food <!-- Main Category -->

 <ul> 
  <li style="display:none"> Pizza </li>    <!-- Category Child Item -->
  <li style="display:none"> Falafel </li>    <!-- Category Child Item -->
  <li style="display:none"> Donuts </li>    <!-- Category Child Item -->
  <li style="display:none"> Burger </li>    <!-- Category Child Item -->
  <li style="display:none"> Cheese Sandwich </li>  <!-- Category Child Item -->
 </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there was no `jquery` tag, I provide a different to @bhargavponnapalli solution, in native Javascript:

```
var food = document.getElementById('food');
var list = food.getElementsByTagName('li');
var hideDiv = true;
for(var i in list) {
    if(typeof list[i] == 'object') {        
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(list[i]);
        if(style.display != 'none') {
            hideDiv = false;
        }
    }
}
if(hideDiv == true) {
    food.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/091oo5g4/2/).